# Sort the array in descending order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to sort the array in descending order. I use `asort` in order to save proper reference to keys. However, `$ind` is null. Why?

```
$selected = array();

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    $selected[] = array('ind' => $i, 'rank' => rand(0,10));
}

asort($selected, SORT_NUMERIC);

$ind = $selected['ind'];
```

Comment: Because `$selected` is the array.... you want a key in a value of `$selected.`

Comment: $ind = $selected[0]['ind'], it says $ind = 0, and in case of $ind = $selected['ind'][0], it says $ind = null, while $selected is Array[10]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your `for()` loop you have something like this:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array (
      [ind] => NUM
      [rank] => NUM 
   [1] => Array (
      [ind] => NUM
      [rank] => NUM
   etcetcetc....
)
```

This is called a multidimensional array, and you access the inner arrays in a similar way as you do single-dimensional arrays.

You can access it with a `$array[0]['ind']`, or possibly even a `foreach()` loop so you get all the values.

```
$ind = array();
foreach($array as $line) {
   $ind[] = $line['ind'];
}
```

Now the `$ind` array has all the values in a single-dimensional array, that you can access with: `$ind[0]` or `$ind[1]`, giving you the `ind` value.